# UITableView with Core Data insertRowsAtIndexPaths causes NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios, core-data, delegates

I am currently in the process of writing a simple table view example for the iPhone but for the life of me I cannot figure out why the following exception occurs.

The work flow is as follows:
I have a UIViewController to which I am adding a UIView. To that view then I am adding a programatically defined UITableView

```
- (id)init{
    [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 280, 180) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    tableView.delegate = self;

    return self;
}
```

Once this is complete I am using a UITableViewDelegate and overwriting the following method which should cause my table to be edited. This is triggered by a button and a selector method of

```
- (void)editList:(id)sender{
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [editButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ApplyChanges.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

There is another method called doneList which gets triggered upon completion but the code isn't getting that far. So once the button is clicked my delegate of setEditing is called and the error is thrown.

Here is the delegate method

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)flag animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"setEditing");
    // Always call super implementation of this method, it needs to do some work
    [super setEditing:flag animated:animated];
    // We need to insert/remove a new row in to table view to say "Add New Item..."
    if (flag) {
        // If entering edit mode, we add another row to our table view
        int count = entries.count;
        NSLog(@"int: %i", count);
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];    
    } else {
        // If leaving edit mode, we remove last row from table view
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[entries count] inSection:0];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    }
}
```

Couple of things about this chunk of code during execution:
1) Initially the "entries" array is empty so the count is 0 which seems to return a not null indexPath object
2) When the entries are populated with bogus data the count increases correctly but the error still occurs
3) I have tried removing the super setEditing call and error still occurs

And finally here is the error.

```
2011-01-12 16:46:13.623 Book[6256:40b] numberOfRowsInSection
2011-01-12 16:46:13.625 Book[6256:40b] numberOfRowsInSection
2011-01-12 16:46:17.658 Book[6256:40b] setEditing
2011-01-12 16:46:17.659 Book[6256:40b] int: 0
2011-01-12 16:46:17.660 Book[6256:40b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UITableView.m:976
2011-01-12 16:46:17.692 Book[6256:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'
```

Please let me know if there is something obvious I am missing, is it possibly that I need to include another delegate method that I am unaware of ?

Comment: Are you sure you want entries.count if you're zero-based in the row array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out folks. It appears that when using a custom UIViewController that sets a UITableViewDelegate you also need to have a UITableViewDataSource set and point the tableViews dataSource to self.

Example code.

Old code

```
// Header File 

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {

}

// Main File

- (id)init{
    [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 280, 180) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    tableView.delegate = self;

    return self;
}
```

Updated working code

```
// Header File 

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

}

// Main File

- (id)init{
    [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 280, 180) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    return self;
}
```